# How to send a variable that have string data read from a file to an sql update query in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, oracle

**Im trying to pass a string in my update query which is read from a text file(this have only one string)**

**Also im trying to update a oracle database table**

**My code looks like this**

```
try:
    with open('update.txt') as file1:
        upd_value = up.read() # This gives me upd_value = 'HELLO_THERE'
    conn = cx_Oracle.connect('usr', 'pwd', dsn_tns)
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    upd_query = """ update some_table set something = %s where some_column = 'some_value', 
                (upd_value,) """
    cursor.execute(upd_query)
except cx_Oracle.DatabaseError as exc:
    err, = exc.args
    print("Oracle-Error-Code:", err.code)
    print("Oracle-Error-Message:", err.message)
finally:
    cursor.close()
    conn.close()
```

**Im getting the following error**

```
Oracle-Error-Code: 911
Oracle-Error-Message: ORA-00911: invalid character
```

It would be great if somebody help me out with this, Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you sure everything is set up correctly regarding using bind variables? https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/bind.html

Comment: Honestly i haven't  been into this concept before, finding it confusing to follow the link you have provided. Could you pls elaborate or tell what's wrong in my code?

Comment: Is "upd_query" just a placeholder for this question or do you tried your code with that query? Otherwise it would be useful to see the real query, because there might be a problem with handover your python variable into the query.

Comment: I have tried the code with 'upd_query', getting the string properly in 'upd_value'. But no luck

Comment: The query contains %-symbol in it, which could throw the error. Are you even running a real database which you are connected to? If you arent connected to a database thats's the first thing you should set up. Then you should become familiar with SQL-queries and then try to understand the link I gave you, how to pass python-variables correctly to the query.

Comment: Yes correct....

Comment: Thats a good suggestion really appreciate. Could you pls write me a query on how to complete my requirement

Comment: In this "theoretical" case it would be something like: upd_query = """update some_table set something = :sql_upd_value where some_column = 'some_value' """
cursor.execute(upd_query, sql_upd_value = upd_value). But this also won't work without a database

Comment: Hey @Jonas, i do connected to a database and your query worked perfectly. Thanks for your time and effort in explaining this. I will go through that link. If you can paste the same query in answers section i can accept it. Anyway thanks!

Comment: Now you have it working, take a look at the cx_Oracle samples https://github.com/oracle/python-cx_Oracle/tree/master/samples for more tips.

Comment: That's a bunch of knowledgeful info, thanks @ChristopherJones